# How to continuously read pcap file while it is also still being written?

Tags: bash, shell, file, pipeline, pcap

I need to continuously read a pcap file recorded by a pcap capture program.

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -w foo.pcap
tcpstat -r foo.pcap -o "pps: %p\n" 1
```

For an example, assume I am recording a pcap by above tcpdump command and trying to read with tcpstat. Here, tcpstat is executing current foo.pcap and finishing its job. What I want is that make it wait for new packages and process them too. You can think is as a tailf command but reads pcap instead text file.

Note that here tcpdump and tcpstat only 2 example of reader and writer processes. They can be any other programs. Also note that reader processes can be more than one. What is the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring the `pcap` stuff (see end of post) to start, and answering the general question:

> ... here tcpdump and tcpstat only 2 example of reader and writer processes. They can be any other programs. Also note that reader processes can be more than one. What is the best way to accomplish that?

So one writer multiple reader problem.

What's the best solution in **Bash**? Probably `tail -F my.log` file. Example:

```
while true; do echo ${RANDOM} >> my.log; sleep 1; done & 
tail -F my.log &
tail -F my.log &
tail -F my.log &
```

There is also `tee` but that writes to multiple files not multiple processes. I guess you could setup a bunch of pipes to processes and use tee.

Note there are plenty of better solutions *not* in Bash that you probably want to use if you want a higher quality solution. One general issue with `tail` and UNIX pipes is that they are stream orientated, and you probably want a message orientated stream. UNIX message queues, a queue server, or maybe sockets can help with that.

---

**On the `pcap` case**

`tail -F` won't work because [pcap file format](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-savefile.5.html) has a header and you can't just start reading from the end of the file like tail -F does. You need to read the whole file start to finish then start tailing. `-n` option to `tail` does that:

```
 tail -n+0 -F foo.pcap  | tcpstat -r- -o "pps: %p\n"
```

Comment: you are ignoring most important part of my question!

Comment: @ibrahim See updated answer. `tail's` -n option does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

tcpstat can read data from stdin:
-r filename
Read all data from filename, which may be a regular file, a named pipe or "-" to read it's data from standard input.
So:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -w foo.pcap &
tail -f foo.pcap | tcpstat -r - -o "pps: %p\n" 1
```

Also, you would run this commands in different termial windows

Comment: I already tried it. tcpstat returning that error. pcap_open(): unknown file format

Answer (score 0):

You need to enhance your tail parameters by "-n+0 -c+1".
Following should do the magic:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -w foo.pcap &
tail -fn+0 -c+1 foo.pcap | tcpstat -r - -o "pps: %p\n" 1
```

-n+0 == begin read from 1st line of the file (plus 0 lines offset from start)

-c+1 == add an extra byte to the output